# How to include module's CSS in CMS pages with module block

Tags: magento2, css, custom-block, cms-pages

I have prepared one module in which I have prepared two .phtml files and included css and js through module layout file. Now, I want to include those .phtml file in different blocks and pages.

I have tried to include .phtml in CMS page with below code:

```
{{block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" template="CompanyName_ModuleName::file.phtml"}}
```

But it only includes .phtml file not CSS.

Here is my module layout file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
<head>
    <css src="CompanyName_ModuleName::css/abc.css"/>
    <css src="CompanyName_ModuleName::css/instapic-slider.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" name="ModuleName_bytag" template="picsbytag.phtml" />
        <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" name="ModuleName_byname" template="picsbyname.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

How I can achieve this to include css with .phtml file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ManthanDave I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: Yes, I have run that command. And I using magento 2's way to call js using require-js-config.js

Comment: Please check the correct answer posted below by me

Answer (score 5):

Put your js file in your custom module **Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/yourjsfile**

Create requirejs-config.js file in your custom_module/view/frontend. add below code in it .

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "instapic": "Vendor_Module/js/instapic-slider"
        }
    }
};
```

Now call the js file in your .phtml template file by writing below code :

**write this at the end of the .phtml file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery', 'instapic'],function($){
        (function() {

        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Also your layout file code should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <css src="CompanyName_Modulename/css/abc.css"/>
        <css src="CompanyName_Modulename/css/instapic-slider.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" name="ModuleName_bytag" template="picsbytag.phtml" />
            <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" name="ModuleName_byname" template="picsbyname.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>
```

After that remove your **pub/static** and **var/generation** folder and run **setup:di:compile** and **setup:static-content:deploy** command

Comment: I have done all this steps before. It doesn't include CSS in other pages.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal ok, can you convert your css to less css like `instapic-slider.css` to `instapic-slider.less` do you have  less file of your css ?

Comment: I have face same issue while implementing owl carousel slider to magento 2 and lastly i have converted `css` to `less` and put it `less css` in `css` folder and call all the css in `_module.less` file and its works fine .  i have call slider on homepage as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the CMS Page editor, go to the 'Design' tab and enter your XML in the 'Layout Update XML' field, without the `page` element:

```
<head>
    <css src="CompanyName_ModuleName::css/abc.css"/>
    <css src="CompanyName_ModuleName::css/instapic-slider.css"/>
    <script src="CompanyName_ModuleName::js/instapic-slider.js"/>
</head>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" name="ModuleName_bytag" template="picsbytag.phtml" />
        <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" name="ModuleName_byname" template="picsbyname.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

Then save the page and clear the cache.

Comment: I don't think so this will be a good solution. Because I want to include this block in multiple pages even in theme's block and pages. In that time this will not help me to include css & js everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after searching & trying so much I got the correct answer through which you can correctly include your CSS with your block.

Create a separate **default.xml** file inside your module layout folder if it does not exist. Then add your code to include CSS in default.xml file.